# php soap calls in loop using same client-object

Tags: php, web-services, loops, soap

I have to call a Soap-Service in a loop so I have to call this service many times.

Which is the better way to handle this:

> A) create the soap-client once and use it for the calls in the loop.
>
> B) create the soap-client object for every call.

The response can be a huge array.

At the moment, I use way A.

I think, it is getting slower at the end of the loop.

If I use B, I have the feeling that it runs faster but that could be wrong.

What is the best approach for this case.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to create one soap-client and use it for the calls in the loop. You can find a similar question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14260685/php-make-soap-calls-in-a-loop).